# Missingness of biomarkers due to lack of measurement

Tags: missing-data

I am working with a dataset composed of ICU and ER patients giving the values of biomarkers measured through various blood and urine panels. Not all of the patients underwent each panel, so in several cases I have missing biomarkers. Patients weren't subject to tests that were considered unnecessary, so for example an ER patient missing their finger wouldn't have observed values of renal biomarkers since there would be no reason to look at them in the ER.

What type of missingness would this be? Is it NMAR if the missingness is due to the value being normal (which is why the doctor chose not to request a test)?

Comment: To better understand your problem, could you say what is your hypothesis of interest?

Comment: I want to impute the missing values if possible, then model a Cox survival analysis with this data.

Comment: You want to use the tests results as predictors? How many variables are missing, how many variables do you have besides these test panels, what is the percentage of missingness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, you can for sure discard the Missing Completely At Random (**MCAR**) assumption. The question is then between Missing At Random (**MAR**) or Missing Not At Random (**MNAR**) assumptions.

Let's hypothetically put the situation where you test to know if someone is using drugs. As you well say, the missingness of the measurements depends on the value of the very same variable: e.g. someone clearly under the influence of a substance would get a urine test applied, while someone that appears sober would not be requested one. In this example, the question then would be if your dataset considers information that would allow you to predict the urine test result: history of drug use, clinical impressions on behavior and speech, triangulation from a partner or family, etc. If the rest of your variables can accurately predict the result of the urine test, it would be **MAR**. Otherwise, we are left with **MNAR**.